# regex for specific filename

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, filenames

I need to validate the filenames before a upload. I thought regex would be the perfect solution for that, but I don't have a clue of regex.

The filenames have all a specific structure.

What I tried myself is: `/([-\d]{2,})_([a-zA-Z\d]+)/`, but this will only match the first numbers and the first tag in the filename.

Example: 100_test-tag1-tag2.gif or 100_test_tag1-tag2.gif

The files have to start with a number and after the number should be a underscore. After that it should at least have one part with a tag. The tags can be separated by a underscore or a hyphen. The tags can occur an infinite number of times. The file ending should be .gif.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @Scamus! We are not a code writing service. So it is required that you show an attempt of your own. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/8106583) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @wuerfelfreak sorry for that. I've tried to make this regex on my own, but I didn't write my attempts in the Question. I will add this now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt is almost complete:

Try this:

```regex
/([-\d]{2,})_([a-zA-Z\d]+)([_-][a-zA-Z\d]+)*\.gif/
```

---

I added this:

```regex
([_-][a-zA-Z\d]+)*
```

which matches an `_` or `-` followed by a tag zero ore more times.
And

```regex
\.gif
```

which matches the trailing .gif.